# why i get this error result = method(y) FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead

Tags: python, postgresql, data-science

I got this error : elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison

```
sf= gpd.read_file(r"C:\Users\nasreddine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\stage_nasseriddine2020\stage_nasseriddine2020\nassereddine_carte_gouv.shp")
print(sf.columns)
se=float(numb1.get())


cur.execute("select distinct nassereddine_carte_gouv.c_gouv  from nassereddine_carte_gouv,disshp where nassereddine_carte_gouv.c_gouv=disshp.id and Shape_leng <='%s'"%(numb1.get())+"and disshp.rowid_ between'%s'"%(numb3.get())+"and '%s'"%(numb2.get()))
rr=cur.fetchall()
s=sf[sf['C_GOUV']==16]['geometry']
for i in rr:
    print(i)
    s=sf[sf['C_GOUV']==i]['geometry']
```

Comment: I got this error 
    result = method(y)
FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison please help

Comment: Hello and welcome on stackoverflow! [Take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

This warning occurs when comparing "int" and "str" in your dataset.
Add `.astype(int)` to your comparison dataset.

```
s=sf[sf['C_GOUV'].astype(int)==16]['geometry']
for i in rr:
    print(i)
    s=sf[sf['C_GOUV'].astype(int)==i]['geometry']
```